# Files in reverse order when Saving As

Tags: 14.04

I am new to Ubuntu 14.04 and have set my file order alphabetically which works when I want to open a file. However when I want to 'Save As' then the file order is Z to A. How do I change this to alphabetical order? All my personal file are stored on a separate hard drive, and I am dual booting with Win Xp.

Answer (score 1):

Just click on the "Name" column to order them ascending or descending.

See this picture for a clarification (my system is localized in Italian, but you can get an idea)

[image: Gif example]

Comment: You might consider adding a screenshot to your answer. :)